# IOS and Android build issues - codenameone

Tags: codenameone

Following error is being thrown when performing IOS and Android builds. Please advise if any have face similar issue.

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: s3.amazonaws.com
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:649)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a network connectivity issue on your side. We use S3 for file transfer.

S3 is an Amazon webservice that a great deal of the internet depends on so it's generally pretty stable.

If you are behind a proxy or firewall run the simulator. Then under the `Simulator` -> `Network` options make sure to configure your proxy settings.